# CATransform3D row/column order

Tags: core-animation, catransform3d

I have a bit of confusion regarding the matrix row/column order of the CATransform3D struct.  The struct defines a matrix like this:

```
[m11 m12 m13 m14]
[m21 m22 m23 m24]
[m31 m32 m33 m34]
[m41 m42 m43 m44]
```

At first, it would seem that the values define rows (so that [m11 m12 m13 m14] forms the first row), but when you create a translation matrix by (tx, ty, tz), the matrix will look like this:

```
[ 1  0  0  0]
[ 0  1  0  0]
[ 0  0  1  0]
[tx ty tz  1]
```

My confusion comes from the fact that this is not a valid translation matrix; multiplying it with a 4-elements column-vector will not translate the point.

My guess is that the CATransform3D struct stores the values in column-order, so that the values [m11 m12 m13 m14] form the first column (and not the first row).

Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `CATransform3D` is in column major order because that is how OpenGL(ES) wants it. Core Animation uses GL in the background for it's rendering. If you want proof, check out the `man` page for `glMultMatrix`:

> **PARAMETERS**
>
> *m* Points to 16 consecutive values that are used as the elements of a 4 x 4 column-major matrix.16 consecutive values that are used as the elements of a 4 x 4 column-major matrix.

This really should be more clear in the docs for `CALayer`.

Comment: Nope, it's not. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CoreAnimationBasics/CoreAnimationBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH2-SW16

Comment: @idz What does the link say? It doesn't seems to deny the column-major assumption.

Comment: @xi.lin See figure 1-8 shows transforms are interpreted as row major.

Comment: @idz I don't think so. It is still column-major. You can try `translate` matrix as example.

Comment: @idz The column major version has the tx, ty, tz coefficients in the 4th column. The diagram clearly shows them in the forth *row*. I've even reproduced the relevant portion in my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Your initial interpretation was correct; `CATransform3D` does define the matrix below:

```
[m11 m12 m13 m14]
[m21 m22 m23 m24]
[m31 m32 m33 m34]
[m41 m42 m43 m44]
```

And yes, although it may be confusing (if you are used to pre-multiplying transform matrices), this yields the translation matrix:

```
[ 1  0  0  0]
[ 0  1  0  0]
[ 0  0  1  0]
[tx ty tz  1]
```

See [Figure 1-8 in the "Core Animation Programming Guide"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CoreAnimationBasics/CoreAnimationBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH2-SW16).

This *is* a valid transformation matrix if you *post-multiply* your transform matrices, which is what Apple does in Core Animation (see Figure 1-7 in the same guide, although beware the equation is missing transpose operations).